# Convert color image to Black and White (not grayscale) depending on color conditions in java

Tags: java, image, image-processing

I have an image(test.jpg) which contains alphabets in different 8 colours.
These 8 colours are:

R G B

0   0   0

0   255 0

0   0   255

0   255 255

255 0   0

255 0   255

255 255 0

255 255 255

I want to color these alphabets with the above 8 colors to BLACK and rest everything to WHITE
I tried doing these by some if statements on red green blue values of pixels but the output is not that good.
Is there any good approach to perform such task.
[Test Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C2zXV.jpg) [Output Image after if statement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/65y6X.jpg)

```
for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
                Color c = new Color(bi.getRGB(j, i));
                      if((c.getRed()>200 && c.getBlue()<60 && c.getGreen()<60)||
                        (c.getRed()>200 && c.getBlue()<60 && c.getGreen()>200) ||
                        (c.getRed()>200 && c.getBlue()>200 && c.getGreen()<60) ||
                        (c.getRed()<60 && c.getBlue()>200 && c.getGreen()<60)||
                        (c.getRed()<60 && c.getBlue()<60 && c.getGreen()>200)||
                        (c.getRed()<60 && c.getBlue()>200 && c.getGreen()>200)|| 
                        (c.getRed()==255 && c.getBlue()==255 && c.getGreen()==255)||    
                        (c.getRed()==0 && c.getBlue()==0 && c.getGreen()==0))
                    imageOut.setRGB(j,i,black.getRGB());
                else
                    imageOut.setRGB(j, i, white.getRGB());
            }
        }
```

Comment: why did you choose to compare at theses huge offsets 60 and 200, rather than exactly 0 and 255?

Comment: I tried this before for detecting just one color(red) but it didnt work. According to me even if the alphabet is said to be red in my image, it will not have exact red value for all pixels.The pixels will be in hue range of red. So it will not detect full red colored alphabet.(i am not sure though of this reason) I will try again doing this for all colors 8 together

Comment: Do that, you might as well take my suggested if condition since it is far more readable and you would have an easier time trying to figure out a better offset.

Comment: I tried this again, but i didn't get any good result. not better than previous one.

Comment: Jpeg images use a compression technique that can introduce artifacts (pixel colour oddities/glitches) into the image. Have you examined the actual pixel values in your problem areas to see how far from the pure colour they actually are?

Comment: Hi @Jason, I created this image in paint just by keeping font and size of alphabets const(Arial 48). When I zoom it, I can see that the pixels are in hue range of that particular color. This logic of 200,60 works fine when the background is not that complex. But since the background itself is having these 8 colors, this logic might not work here. Hence I was looking for some better approach to perform such task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the original you can do subtraction.

Otherwise you can't get a perfect result - if you are after that

since completely separated intervals cannot be guarranteed

You may have to go into segmentation but that wont give you perfect result either

See if storing in png helps

Answer (score 0):

Test for the exact RGB values that you listed then the program will do what you specified. for example...

if((c.getRed()==255 && c.getBlue()==0 && c.getGreen()==0)||

Answer (score 0):

I would change the if statement in the following way:

```
int red = c.getRed(), green = c.getGreen(), blue = c.getBlue();
if ((red   == 255 || red   == 0) &&
    (green == 255 || green == 0) &&
    (blue  == 255 || blue  == 0)) {
    imageOut.setRGB(j,i,black.getRGB());
} else {
    imageOut.setRGB(j, i, white.getRGB());
}
```

Apart from that you can afterwards iterate over all pixels once again and check that every black pixel has *a lot* of other black pixels around. That way you remove the little black sparkles in some places.

The completely black area on the right however will be very hard to remove

Comment: it didn't give such nice output though. I changed offsets to 30 and 230.. i am getting acceptable output for 6 colors but still black and white letters are not in acceptable range. My aim is to treat this output image for template matching. My template is a black alphabet with white background. This is the reason I m trying to convert my color image to such format